# How to update database if not already set... and does it save memory?

Tags: memory-management, mysqli

I want to update a value if it is not already set.

Say I have the table "shipping" with field named "status". 
Some are set to shipped, some are not.
I have some IDs that I want update the status to shipped if they are not already set.

A) `UPDATE shipping SET status = "shipped" WHERE ID in (2, 4, 6) AND status != "shipped"`

is what I have so far

B) Does it even save memory to only update the ones that need it?

Comment: Memory? Or do you mean disk space (for transaction logs)?

Comment: @Thilo, I mean memory. Would it take less memory/time to only update the ones I need?

Comment: /time? It has to take less time to touch fewer records. It don't think it matters in the grand scheme of things unless you have thousands of redundant updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly, depending on your table schema and indexes

mysql already compares the old contents when setting a field, and does not write the row if the contents after the update remain unchanged.

However, to test the old contents, it must load the row.  If you have a lot of columns, that can take both time and memory (mysql internally unpacks varchar columns to their maximum width).

But if the query can use an index that contains status (eg `add index (ID, status)`) and you are explicitly checking the status in your query, then it can check which rows must be changed from a fast-to-read index and can omit loading the rows only to test whether they need to be updated.